# AnyLogic getHomeLocation() error "Undefined for the type"

Tags: anylogic

I am using AnyLogic 8 University 8.7.0 version and doing Agent Based Modelling. I have created a ResourcePool of Auto agents and I want to store the initial locations of autos (GISPoints) in a variable. Using the unit.getHomeLocation() method is giving me the error: "The method getHomeLocation() is undefined for the type Auto". Here, "unit" is the name of ResourcePool unit of the type Auto.

Any workaround for this will be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your project browser, click on the agent "Auto". In its properties, under the tab ***Agent in flowcharts*** make sure ***Use in flowcharts as:*** is specified as "Resource Unit".

Let me know if this resolves it.

[image]

Comment: I tried this out and it resolved my issue. Thanks a ton!